# Is there existing code that will convert Japanese search strings in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am writing a app that should handle Japanese search strings.

I need a couple of utility functions:

- Converts Hiragana alphabets to Katakana alphabets and vive versa.
- Convert half width to full width characters.

Does anything already exist in Objective C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For converting half-width to full-width Katakana check this out...

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/izsak/20100508/1273334470

The Hiragana to Katakana is a trivial util method with a giant switch statement...

> switch (hiragana) { case @"あ": return @"ア"; .... }

Trivializing it above but you have to offer non-strings to do the comparisons in a switch obviously.

Comment: Thank you. The link is exactly what I was looking for. Essentially Apple have already written conversion functions in the core foundation layer.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTransform

Comment: Anytime! You might want to pay extra attention to the older kana that've almost fallen out of common use like "ヱ", now that I think of it.  I haven't tried it out personally.

Comment: Don't use a switch. CFStringTransform is all that's needed. Here's another link. http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/